# Strange messages when starting

Tags: 20.04, startup

My Ubuntu is taking longer than usual to start up and there are some strange messages rolling on the screen before the login screen appears (image attached). Anyone can help me figure out what is happening?[image]

Comment: You have several clear messages in there. CRASH REPORT some service is crashing actual it looks like several. Have you done something recently?

Comment: Nothing different. But the system automatically updated this morning and it all ent back to normal. Thanks for your attention.